# How do I check web visitor access in my EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do I check web visitor access in my EC2. So I can see the visitor IP and the url/file they are accessing

Comment: hii welcome to stack overflow, for checking visitor information you need to process your server logs the server logs are usually found in /var/logs/apache if you are using apache server let me know if you need further help i'm open for discussion

Comment: There is no /var/logs/apache. what should I do next? something not installed? Sorry, still new in this

Comment: which web server you are using ? please explain more what you did after you created your ec2 instance

Comment: I'm using the bitnami to install wordpress https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/ It's using Ubuntu

Comment: then in your case it can be found in /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/access_log directory